# How to replace all characters except a numeral (200, 200.45 etc.) from a string in php?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have few strings where i need to extract only the prices in php (which will obviously be numerals).
The use cases are follows:

```
     1) Rs. 23,459.45                 desired output = 23459.45
     2)Our best price 23,459.45       desired output = 23459.45
```

etc.

I gave the above use cases to give an idea that the preceding characters could be anything.

Please help!

Comment: So basically you need to convert a string to numeral?

Comment: @danis  yes.. thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$arr = array(
    'Rs. 23,459.45 ',
    'Our best price 23,459.45 ',
);
foreach($arr as $string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+),?(\d{3})(\.\d{2})?.*$/', "$1$2$3", $string);
    echo $string,"\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
23459.45
23459.45
```

Answer (score 2):

It's:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $string);
```

-but note, this will not validate numbers or provide valid result in common case since string could contain something like `'foo . bar,baz . price 20.5 with .6 discount'` - end result will be not a valid number. So code above answers the question about "how to replace", but does not fit validating a number (and you've not mentioned if that is your goal).

About validating a number - such question will be ambiguous because it's not obvious how to convert `..20.5.6` (which will be result for string above). But if you need only to check that, use [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/is_numeric) on `$result`, like this:

```
$string = 'foo . bar,baz . price 20.5 with .6 discount';
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $string);
$result = is_numeric($result)?(float)$result:null;
```

Comment: the strings will be in the format that I had provided.. so I wouldn't need to validate it hopefully... with regard to your answer, for the first use case "Rs. 23, 459.45"  won't your answerl give me an output .23459.45 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to validate the above strings. When this function valiadates Rs. , it will return two dots, so I used *ltrim* to remove the first dot.

```
<?php

//$s = "Rs. 23,459.45"; 

$s= "Our best price 23,459.45";

echo $result = ltrim(preg_replace("/[^0-9.]+/", "", $s),'.');

?>
```

http://codepad.org/cyH5OWyE